# Airflow tasks in queue but never scheduled

Tags: python, airflow

With Airflow 1.8.1, I am using LocalExecutor with `max_active_runs_per_dag=16`, I called a for loop to dynamic create tasks (~100) with PythonOperators. Most time the tasks completed without any issues. However, it is still possible that task is with `queue` status but scheduler seems forget it, I can clear the task and able to rerun the queued task and worked, but would like to know how to avoid stuck in queue.

Comment: Could you share some log output and source code if possible? That'll make it easier to help out.

Comment: What is the `parallelism` config of your LocalExecutor? This one defines the number of running processes.

Comment: @FokkoDriesprong parallelism = 32

Comment: This is due to a issue with 1.8.1 as mentioned here and should be fixed at 1.9 https://stackoverflow.com/a/46878502/1451653