# Airflow 1.9.0 is queuing but tasks are not running

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Airflow stopped running tasks all of a sudden. Below are all running

`airflow scheduler
airflow webserver
airflow worker`

webui message

> All dependencies are met but the task instance is not running. In most
>   cases this just means that the task will probably be scheduled soon
>   unless:
>   - The scheduler is down or under heavy load
>
> If this task instance does not start soon please contact your Airflow
>   administrator for assistance.

Scheduler seems to be in a loop, keeps repeating the below messages. WebUI shows tasks are in queued state. Tried restarting the scheduler, didn't help.

```
[2018-11-17 22:03:45,809] {{jobs.py:1607}} DEBUG - Starting Loop...
[2018-11-17 22:03:45,809] {{jobs.py:1627}} INFO - Heartbeating the process manager
[2018-11-17 22:03:45,810] {{jobs.py:1662}} INFO - Heartbeating the executor
[2018-11-17 22:03:45,810] {{base_executor.py:103}} DEBUG - 124 running task instances
[2018-11-17 22:03:45,810] {{base_executor.py:104}} DEBUG - 0 in queue
[2018-11-17 22:03:45,810] {{base_executor.py:105}} DEBUG - 76 open slots
[2018-11-17 22:03:45,810] {{base_executor.py:132}} DEBUG - Calling the <class 'airflow.executors.celery_executor.CeleryExecutor'> sync method
[2018-11-17 22:03:45,810] {{celery_executor.py:80}} DEBUG - Inquiring about 124 celery task(s)
```

Airflow setup:
`apache-airflow[celery, redis, all]==1.9.0`

I also checked these posts but didn't help me:

[Airflow 1.9.0 is queuing but not launching tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021055/airflow-1-9-0-is-queuing-but-not-launching-tasks)

[Airflow tasks get stuck at "queued" status and never gets running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853013/airflow-tasks-get-stuck-at-queued-status-and-never-gets-running)

Comment: Have you tried clearing the dag runs?

Comment: yes. I also tried re-running the last successful dag run also didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. **This is a problem when you create your build on or after 2018-11-15** Turns out `apache-airflow[celery, redis, all]==1.9.0` takes the latest version of [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) `3.0.1` which does not work with celery `4.2.1`.
Solution is to use redis-py `2.10.6`

`redis==2.10.6
apache-airflow[celery, all]==1.9.0`