# Airflow 2.5.1 - Tasks stuck in queued

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using Airflow 2.5.1 running on top of AKS, I am facing issues where the tasks in running DAGs are stuck in queue and not starting.

stalled_task_timeout = 600 is implemented but it does not seem working.

Could you please help and please let me know if you faced similar issues and how do you resolved it?

To have all tasks in DAGs running as per expected

Comment: there are many different reasons why this happens. could you share more details - logs from scheduler, your worker setup?

Comment: check this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853013/airflow-tasks-get-stuck-at-queued-status-and-never-gets-running

Answer (score 0):

[image: Picture of airflow dag]It can happen if your dags are paused.
You can try running after turning on your dag.

Comment: hi there, the dag itself is running, but the task under the dag is stuck in queue and not starting nor running

Answer (score 0):

This [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/28120) partially explains why tasks can get stuck in queued for longer than `stalled_task_timeout`.

`stalled_task_timeout` has been replaced by [AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__TASK_QUEUED_TIMEOUT](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#config-scheduler-task-queued-timeout) starting in Airflow 2.6.0, which resolves this problem and reliably handles tasks that get stuck in the queued state.